# iPhone 5c and anything running bluetooth 4.0 has wcsession timout

Tags: bluetooth, watch

I have tested my code on the iPhone 6 plus running 9.0 with apple watch 1 and iPhone 7 running 10.0 with apple watch 2.

```
//HeartrateModel_Phone.m

#import "HeartrateModel_Phone.h"

@implementation HeartrateModel_Phone
{
    Communicator * comm;
    communicatorStatus commStatus;

    HealthDataService * hkService;
    workoutStatus monitoringStatus;
}

@synthesize delegate;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        comm = [[Communicator alloc]init];
        hkService = [[HealthDataService alloc]init];

        monitoringStatus = noWorkoutActivated;
        commStatus = noCommunicationActivated;

        comm .delegate = self;
        hkService.delegate = self;

        bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

        [comm start];
    }
    return self;
}//eom

-(void)activate
{
    [comm start];
}//eom

/*
//disable to remove singleton option
+(HeartrateModel_Phone *)sharedInstance
{
    static HeartrateModel_Phone * sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[HeartrateModel_Phone alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}//eom
*/


#pragma mark - Bluetooth 
/*!
 * @discussion Accepts a CBCentralManager and returns the bluetooth status
 * @param CBCentralManager
 * @return bluetoothStatus
 */
-(bluetoothStatus)getBluetoothStatus:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    switch (central.state)
    {
        case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
            return bluetooth_notSupported;
            break;
        case CBManagerStateUnauthorized:
            return bluetooth_unathorized;
            break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
            return bluetooth_off;
            break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
            return bluetooth_on;
            break;
        default:
            return bluetooth_unknown;
            break;
    }
}//eom


#pragma mark Bluetooth Delegates
-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    bluetoothStatus status = [self getBluetoothStatus:central];
    [delegate heartrateModelBluetoothStatusChanged:status];

    if (VERBOSE) {
       NSLog(@"%@ Bluetooth '%@'", self, hrModelBluetoothStatusToString(status));
    }
}//eom

#pragma mark - Start Workout Process
/*!
 * @discussion Starts heartrate mode by sending a message to watch to start workout
    if the following conditions are met:
 * @brief 1) bluetooth must be enable/turned on
 * @brief 2a) to start watch app automatically the iOS version must be 10 & above
 */
-(void)start
{
    //making sure bluetooth is on
    bluetoothStatus BTstatus = [self getBluetoothStatus:bluetoothManager];
    if (BTstatus == bluetooth_on)
    {
        //checking OS version
        NSOperatingSystemVersion osVersion = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo]operatingSystemVersion];
        NSInteger currOSVersion = osVersion.majorVersion;

        if (currOSVersion >= 10)
        {
            //checking watch is ready
            if( ((comm .session) .isPaired)
               && ((comm .session) .isWatchAppInstalled) )
            {
                //setup workout configuration
                HKWorkoutConfiguration * wkConfig = [[HKWorkoutConfiguration alloc]init];
                wkConfig.activityType = HKWorkoutActivityTypeOther;
                wkConfig.locationType = HKWorkoutSessionLocationTypeUnknown;

                //attempt to start watch app automatically
                [(hkService .hkStore) startWatchAppWithWorkoutConfiguration:wkConfig
                          completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error)
                 {
                     [delegate heartrateModelStartWorkResult:success withError:error];

                     //start monitoring heartrate data from healthkit
                     if (success){
                         [self startReading_HeartrateData];
                     }
                 }];
            }
            else
            {
                //communication not possible
                NSErrorDomain errorDomain= @"";
                NSInteger errorCode = 1111;
                NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:errorDomain
                                                      code:errorCode
                                                  userInfo:nil];
                [delegate heartrateModelStartWorkResult:false  withError:error];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //sending a live message to watch
            [self messageStartWorkout:true];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //notify that bluetooth status is not on
         [delegate heartrateModelBluetoothStatusChanged:BTstatus];
    }
}//eom

/*!
 * @discussion Stops the Heartrate model, sends message to watch to stop workout and stops monitoring healthkit for heartrate data
 */
-(void)end
{
    [self stopReading_HeartrateData];
    [self messageEndWorkout];
}//eom

#pragma mark - Live Message Start Workout
/*!
 * @discussion Sends a start workout commands to counterpart via live message
 * @param BOOL whether the listener/delegate VC would be notified of message delivery failures
 */
-(void)messageStartWorkout:(BOOL)reportFailure
{
    NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * messageToSend = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                    hrModelKeysToString(monitorKey_Command), hrModelKeysToString(monitor_key),
                                                    hrModelCommandToString(monitorCommand_start),hrModelCommandToString(monitor_Command), nil];

    [(comm .session) sendMessage:messageToSend
                    replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage)
     {

     } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
         //communication not possible
         if (reportFailure) {
             [delegate heartrateModelStartWorkResult:false  withError:error];
         }
     }];
}//eom

/*!
 * @discussion Sends a stop workout commands to counterpart via live message
 * @discussion if live message fails, sends a background message
 */
-(void)messageEndWorkout
{
    NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * messageToSend = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    hrModelKeysToString(monitorKey_Command), hrModelKeysToString(monitor_key),
    hrModelCommandToString(monitorCommand_end),hrModelCommandToString(monitor_Command), nil];

    [(comm .session) sendMessage:messageToSend
                    replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage)
     {
         //NSLog(@"reply message: %@", replyMessage);
     } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error)
     {
         //sending background message - optional
         [comm sendApplicationContext:messageToSend];
     }];
}//eom

-(void)messageRequestForWorkoutStatus
{
    NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * messageToSend = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                hrModelKeysToString(monitorKey_Command), hrModelKeysToString(monitor_key),
                hrModelCommandToString(monitorCommand_status),hrModelCommandToString(monitor_Command), nil];

    [(comm .session) sendMessage:messageToSend
                    replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage)
     {
         //NSLog(@"reply message: %@", replyMessage);
     } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error)
     {

     }];
}//eom

#pragma mark - Health Store Permission
/*!
 * @discussion Request Heartrate Healthkit permission
 * @return BOOL success
 * @return NSError any errors with healthkit permission
 */
-(void)requestPermission:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error)) completionBlock
{
    [hkService requestPermission:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
    {
        completionBlock(success, error);
    }];
}//eom

#pragma mark - Communicator Delegates
-(void)communicatorActionStatus:(communicatorStatus)status
{
    commStatus = status;

    if (VERBOSE)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ Communication Status: '%@'", self, communicatorToString(status));
    }
}//eom

-(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)communicatorDidReceivedLiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message
{
    [self handleMessageReceived:message];

    NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * reply = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                                            initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Success", @"Received", nil];
    if (delegate == nil)
    {
        reply = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Failed", @"Received", nil];
    }

    return reply;
}//eom

-(void)communicatorDidReceivedBackgroundMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message
{
    //nothing to do - not implemented for phone to received background messages
}//eom

-(void)communicatorStateChanged:(WCSession *)session
{
    if (session .reachable) {
        [self messageRequestForWorkoutStatus];
    }
}//eom

#pragma mark Communication Helpers
/*!
 * @discussion Handles message received and calls the corresponding handler
 * @param NSDictionary Message Received from counterpart
 */
-(void)handleMessageReceived:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)messageRcvd
{
    if (VERBOSE)
    {
        NSLog(@"[hrModel] message RCVD %@", messageRcvd);
    }

    NSString * keyReceived = [messageRcvd objectForKey:hrModelKeysToString(monitor_key)];

    //response / status
    if ([keyReceived isEqualToString: hrModelKeysToString(monitorKey_Response)])
    {
        NSString * responseReceived = [messageRcvd objectForKey:hrModelResponseToString(monitor_Response)];
        [self handleMessage_Response:responseReceived];
    }
    //error
    else if ([keyReceived isEqualToString: hrModelKeysToString(monitorKey_Error)])
    {
        NSString * errorReceived = [messageRcvd objectForKey:hrModelErrorToString(monitor_Response)];
        [self handleMessage_Error:errorReceived];
    }
    //Command
    else if ([keyReceived isEqualToString: hrModelKeysToString(monitorKey_Command)])
    {
        NSString * commandReceived = [messageRcvd objectForKey:hrModelCommandToString(monitor_Command)];
        [self handleMessage_Command:commandReceived];
    }
}//eom

/*!
 * @discussion Handles the response received from counterpart
 * @param NSString Response received
 */
-(void)handleMessage_Response:(NSString *)responseRcvd
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
    ^{
        if ([responseRcvd isEqualToString:hrModelResponseToString(monitorResponse_started)])
        {
            monitoringStatus = started;
            [self startReading_HeartrateData];
        }
        else  if ([responseRcvd isEqualToString:hrModelResponseToString(monitorResponse_ended)])
        {
            monitoringStatus = ended;
            [self stopReading_HeartrateData];
        }
        else  if ([responseRcvd isEqualToString:hrModelResponseToString(monitorResponse_notStarted)])
        {
            monitoringStatus = noWorkoutActivated;
            //no need to report failure to start since the nstimer on vc would be trigger
        }
    });
}//eom


/*!
 * @discussion Handles the response received from counterpart
 * @param NSString Response received
 */
-(void)handleMessage_Error:(NSString *)errorRcvd
{
    monitoringStatus = noWorkoutActivated;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
   ^{
        if ([errorRcvd isEqualToString:hrModelErrorToString(monitorError_workout)])
        {
            monitoringStatus = error_workout;
        }
        else  if ([errorRcvd isEqualToString:hrModelErrorToString(monitorError_healthkit)])
        {
            monitoringStatus = error_healthkit;
        }
        else  if ([errorRcvd isEqualToString:hrModelErrorToString(monitorError_communicator)])
        {
            monitoringStatus = error_communicator;
        }
   });
}//eom


/*!
 * @discussion Handles the command received from counterpart
 * @param NSString Command received
 */
-(void)handleMessage_Command:(NSString *)commandRcvd
{
    //nothing to do - not implemented to received commands
}//eom

#pragma mark - Health Store Heartrate Reading
/*!
 * @discussion Requests to Start monitoring healthkit for heartrate data
 */
-(void)startReading_HeartrateData
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [hkService startHeartrateWithPollingTime:1.5
                   andSamplesWithSecondsBack:-25.0];
    });
}//eom

/*!
 * @discussion Requests to Stop monitoring healthkit for heartrate data
 */
-(void)stopReading_HeartrateData
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [hkService stopPollingHeartrates];
   });
}//eom

#pragma mark - HealthData Service Delegates
-(void)healthDataServicePollingSamplesReceived:(NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> *)samples
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        HKQuantitySample * lastHrSample = [samples firstObject];

        //value
        HKQuantity * hrValue = lastHrSample.quantity;
        double hr = [hrValue doubleValueForUnit:hkService.hrUnit];

        //dates
        NSDate * startDate = lastHrSample.startDate;
        NSDate * endDate = lastHrSample.endDate;

        [delegate heartrateModelDidReceiveHeartrate:hr
                                      withStartDate:startDate
                                         andEndDate:endDate];
        if (VERBOSE)
        {
            NSLog(@"[hrModel] hr %f |\n start %@ |\n end %@ ", hr, [startDate debugDescription], [endDate debugDescription]);
        }

    });
}//eom

@end
```

When I run my code with the iPhone 5c running 10.0 and apple watch 3.0, it will connect but it is inconsistent. Sometimes I would get wcsession timeout error and it failed to deliver the message.

Comment: What language? Can you post your code?

Comment: it in objective - c but the language does not matter. I will post my code.